# Splunk join with an in-memory record

Tags: join, splunk

Sorry for the lame question, I am new to Splunk.

What I am trying to do is to join my search result with a declared in the search body fake record, something like

```
index=... 
| joint type=outer <column> 
[ | <here declare a record to join with> 
......
```

The idea is to make sure there is at least one record in the resulting search. There are the following cases expected:

1. the original search returns records
2. the original search does not return anything because the result is filtered
3. the original search does not return anything because the source is empty

I need to distinguish cases 2 and 3, which the join is for. The fake record will eliminate the case 3 so I will only need to filter the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way to handle the case of no results returned.  Use the `appendpipe` command to test for that condition and add fields needed in later commands.

```
| appendpipe [ stats count | eval column="The source is empty" 
  | where count=0 | fields - count ]
```